# How do I select an embedded element with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I need some help selecting the button in the example below. I am working with Wordpress and when I try to add a custom class to my button, it only adds it to the div that the button is in.

```html
<div class="basic">
  <button class="btn">Content</button>
</div>
```

Now I want to add some JS that changes the background color of the button when another button is clicked. When I select the div with the class assigned by me, the background color of the button doesn't change. I would have to select the button directly but I don't know how.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This question shows zero research effort! - Please search google or SO for "How to select an element with JavaScript" - "How To change the background color of an element with JavaScript" (though CSS and classes are probably better) and search for "How execute JavaScript when clicking a button" - When you have the code you think should work and have issues with it, post it here in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you figure out what might be wrong.

Comment: @Nope I think I should have been more precise in my question. The thing is that I only want to select buttons that are within a div with the class of "basic". I know how basic JS Selectors work but I am having trouble selecting an embedded element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are several options to select the button:**

```
querySelector
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.btn')); // Via its class name
console.log(document.querySelector('button')); // via its tag name
```

```html
<div class="basic">
  <button class="btn">Content</button>
</div>
```

`querySelector` returns the first matching element.

`querySelectorAll` returns **all** matching elements.

---

```
getElementsByClassName
```

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0]); // Select the first element, because getElementsByClassName returns a HTMLCollection!
```

```html
<div class="basic">
  <button class="btn">Content</button>
</div>
```

---

```
getElementsByTagName
```

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]); // Again select the first one!
```

```html
<div class="basic">
  <button class="btn">Content</button>
</div>
```

**Now let's solve your problem:**

```js
// You can use either querySelector, getElementsByTagName, or getElementsByClassName. I decided for querySelector

function changeColor() {
  document.querySelector('.btn').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<div class="basic">
  <button class="btn">Content</button><button onclick="changeColor()">Change Color!</button>
</div>
```

**Edit**

If you want to select only the buttons whithin a specific div, you can do it this way:

```js
function changeColor() {
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName('basic')[0]; // Get the specific div
  var buttons = div.getElementsByClassName('btn'); // Get the buttons by class, but only within the div

  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) { // Loop through the HTMLCollection and apply the CSS to every element
    buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="basic">
  <button class="btn">Content</button>
  <button class="btn">Content</button>
  <button class="btn">Content</button>
</div>
<button class="btn">I won't get selected</button>
<button onclick="changeColor()">Change color</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I should have been more clear though. I only want to select the buttons that are inside a div with the class of "basic". If I choose query Selector for other classes, my selection will be bigger than I want it to be.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it. However, I get an error saying "div.getElementsByClassName is not a function"

Comment: Did `document.getElementsByClassName('basic')[0]` get the div correctly? @PhilippK